# Commutators of unbounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two linear operators on a separable, possibly infinite dimensional, Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.  If both $A$ and $B$ are bounded, then one can use the triangle inequality to show that the commutator $AB-BA$ is also bounded.  My question, then, is does there exist a Hilbert space $H$ and two operators $A, B \in \mathcal{B\mathcal{(H)}}$, with at least one of them unbounded, such that the commutator $AB-BA$ is bounded?

Note that if $A = \lambda B$ for some constant $\lambda$ then the answer is trivial.

Comment: As you pose the question, the answer is yes. Just let A be an unbounded linear operator and B be the 0 operator.

Comment: A less trivial example: $A(f)(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and $B(f)(x) = xf(x)$, then $AB - BA$ is the identity.